# Google Maps mulltiple markers, infowindow, input XML, Fluster2

Tags: jquery, google-maps, marker, infowindow

So far, and thanks to duncan, most of my questions are solved. But I came up to a new issue... It seems that I have to study jquery further...

I have found an interesting tool for clustering. [Fluster2](http://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/2009/12/11/clustering-for-google-maps-v3-with-fluster2/) seems helpful but with no information on how to use it... None of the examples I managed to find online, give explanations how to use Fluster2 with jquery...

Below is my code...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>My map</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="util.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("maps", "3",  {other_params : "sensor=false"});
  google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.5, 25.1419);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    jQuery.get("genXML.php", {}, function(data) {
        jQuery(data).find("marker").each(function() {
            var marker = jQuery(this);
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(marker.attr("lat")), parseFloat(marker.attr("lng")));
            var shop_type = parseInt(marker.attr("type"), 10);
            var address = marker.attr("address");
            var magazi = marker.attr("name");
            var city = marker.attr("city");
            var area = marker.attr("area");
            var tk = marker.attr("postal");

            switch(shop_type) {
                case 0: 
                    typos = "Something"; 
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    typos = "Grocery"; 
                    break; 
                case 2: 
                    typos = "Coffee"; 
                    break; 

                // .........


                case 19: 
                    typos = "Bar"; 
                    break; 
                case 20: 
                    typos = "Club"; 
                    break; 
            }

            var markicon = "icons/0.png";
            if (shop_type >= 1 && shop_type <= 20) {
                markicon = "icons/32/" + shop_type + ".png";
            } else { markicon = "icons/0.png"; }

            var contentString = '<div><b style="font-size:14px">' + magazi + '</b><br/><i style="font-size:12px">' + typos + '</i><div style="float:right; margin-right:10px;"><img src="icons/b/' + shop_type + '.png" width="74" height="100" /></div><p style="font-size:12px"><b>Διεύθυνση:</b> ' + address + '<br /><b>Πόλη:</b> ' + city + '<br /><b>Περιοχή:</b> ' + area + '<br /><b>T.K.:</b> ' + tk + '</p></div>';
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                icon: markicon,
                map: map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {         
                infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        });
    });
}

  google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the XML file has this structure:

```
<markers>
    <marker name="Spot name 1" city="Fanari" area="Rodopi" address="Fanari" postal="67063" type="0" lat="40.96065055467095" lng="25.130796432495117"/>
    <marker name="Spot name 2" city="Fanari" area="Rodopi" address="Fanari" postal="67063" type="0" lat="40.96065055467095" lng="25.192596532495117"/>
</markers>
```

So can someone help me out with this? Any help, idea or guide will be very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up Google Maps API 2 and API 3 code, which isn't going to work, as they're not compatible with each other.

e.g. this is API 3 code:

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            icon: markicon,
            map: map
        });
```

but this is API 2 code:

```
var markicon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
```

You should definitely do everything in API 3, as API 2 has been deprecated for some time.

Having said that, you need to move the logic surrounding which icon to use inside where you get the XML data then create each marker.  Something like this:

```
jQuery.get("genXML.php", {}, function(data) {
    jQuery(data).find("marker").each(function() {
        var marker = jQuery(this);
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(marker.attr("lat")), parseFloat(marker.attr("lng")));

        var shop_type = parseInt(marker.attr("type"), 10);
        var markicon = "icons/0.png";

        if (shop_type >= 1 && shop_type <= 20) {
            markicon = "icons/" & shop_type & ".png";
        }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            icon: markicon,
            map: map
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. From what I've found here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884085/google-maps-api-v3-gicon-is-not-defined, there's no need for the API 2 code... so the markicon variable can be avoided and use the code on the marker like this: `icon: url`. But my concern is the `if (shop_type == 1) url = "icons/1.png";`

Comment: duncan that was great! Thank you for showing me the proper way.